# How do I add mozc as an input method for fctix from the command line?

Tags: mozc

Don't wanna have to use the fctix configruation GUI.

Mozc is a japanese input method by google

Comment: Hello. Based on the lack of info in this question no help can be offered. What version of Ubuntu? What configuration each time?

Comment: The fctix configruation. Ubuntu version 21.

Comment: There is no such version of Ubuntu as 21

Comment: Its Ubuntu 21.10

Comment: You are making it quite hard to help you. What do you need to do with this config tool each time?

Comment: edited the question

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu, I don't know what you mean, you can't set configuration without GUI. 日本語で質問する事も可能です

Comment: I want to be able to automate setting up my computer and I want to know how to add mozc using the terminal.